# After creating second list item, button inside first list item perform operation on second list item

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    public class FragAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    WeakReference<Context> downloadsWeakReference;
    List<DownloadRequest> downloadsPojos;
    Button pause, resume, cancel, open, remove;

    public FragAdapter(WeakReference<Context> downloadsWeakReference, List<DownloadRequest> downloadsPojos) {
        this.downloadsWeakReference = downloadsWeakReference;
        this.downloadsPojos = downloadsPojos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (downloadsPojos != null) {
            return downloadsPojos.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        if (downloadsPojos != null) {
            return downloadsPojos.get(i);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(downloadsWeakReference.get()).inflate(R.layout.download_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        }
        ProgressBar progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView down_progress = view.findViewById(R.id.down_progress);
        TextView download_size = view.findViewById(R.id.download_size);
        TextView status = view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        pause = view.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        resume = view.findViewById(R.id.resume);
        open = view.findViewById(R.id.open);
        remove = view.findViewById(R.id.remove);

        pause.setTag(i);
        resume.setTag(i);
        remove.setTag(i);
        cancel.setTag(i);

        DownloadRequest downloadRequest = downloadsPojos.get(i);

        progressBar.setMax((int) downloadRequest.getTotalBytes());
        progressBar.setProgress((int) downloadRequest.getDownloadedBytes());
        down_progress.setText(String.valueOf((int) downloadRequest.getDownloadedBytes() / 100));
        name.setText(downloadRequest.getFileName());
        download_size.setText(String.valueOf((int) downloadRequest.getTotalBytes() / 1000000));
        //status.setText(String.valueOf(PRDownloader.getStatus(downloadsPojo.getDownloadId())));
        cancel.setText(R.string.cancel);
        pause.setText(R.string.pause);
        resume.setText(R.string.resume);

        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        resume.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        open.setOnClickListener(this);
        remove.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void updateResults(List<DownloadRequest> results) {
        downloadsPojos = results;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void hideView() {
        cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        open.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.cancel:
                int cancelTag = (int) view.getTag();
                PRDownloader.cancel(Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(cancelTag).getDownloadId());
                for (int i = 0; i < Constant.downloadsPojoList.size(); i++) {
                    if (Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(i).getDownloadId() == Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(cancelTag).getDownloadId()) {
                        Log.e("constant", "constant");
                        Constant.downloadsPojoList.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                updateResults(Constant.downloadsPojoList);
                break;
            case R.id.pause:
                int pos = (int) view.getTag();
                PRDownloader.pause(Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(pos).getDownloadId());
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                resume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.resume:
                int posi = (int) view.getTag();
                PRDownloader.resume(Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(posi).getDownloadId());
                Log.e("resume", String.valueOf(posi));
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.open:
                //For showing downloads folder.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "sachin")), "*/*");
                downloadsWeakReference.get().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Downloads using"));
                break;
            case R.id.remove:
                int removeTag = (int) view.getTag();
                for (int i = 0; i < Constant.downloadsPojoList.size(); i++) {
                    if (PRDownloader.getStatus(Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(i).getDownloadId()) == PRDownloader.getStatus(Constant.downloadsPojoList.get(removeTag).getDownloadId())) {
                        Constant.downloadsPojoList.remove(i);
                        Log.e("removed", "removed");
                    }
                }
                updateResults(Constant.downloadsPojoList);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

> In this list each list item has five button PAUSE, RESUME, CANCEL, OPEN, REMOVE. In which two buttons will show at a time and other button visibility will become gone.
>   This is an download list that shows which file is downloading with two buttons, CANCEL and PAUSE, after clicking PAUSE button, PAUSE visibility will become GONE and RESUME visibility will become VISIBLE, and after clicking RESUME button RESUME's visibility becomes GONE and PAUSE visibility becomes VISIBLE.
>   So, the problem is when I download two file and click the pause button of first item, the resume button will appear on the second item not on the first.And it forbid me to pause second downloading.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce boolean variables in DownloadRequest model like **isResume**, **isPause**, etc.
After variables field applied in your model, try to change boolean true/false in conditions whenever you click on **PAUSE**, **RESUME**, etc button and make sure you do **notifyDataSetChanged()**.

This will solve your issue.

If you still facing any issue then please provide model and activity code.